# C# WPF button click

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5

I wounder if there is a way to check if a key is clicked?

What I want to achieve is creating something like text editor, I have finished most of the parts. Now when I press on a button, I have a function under element `PreviewKeyUp` and the other `PreviewKeyDown` ... Is there something like `PreviewKeyClick` or `KeyClick`?

PS: I'm using visual studio 2010 and compiling against .NET Framework 3.5 ... I know I can use 4.0 but 3.5 is due to restrictions on client PC. The application targets a specific client and I can't update the .NET Framework on the client machine. If more details is needed, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I enable PreviewClick using InputBindings in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590924/can-i-enable-previewclick-using-inputbindings-in-wpf)

Comment: @Conrad Frix: not a duplicate, the one you`re referring to is for listViews!! not for textBoxes and keyboard button clicks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, for text editors you would need to handle [TextInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.textinput.aspx) (or [PreviewTextInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput.aspx)) and KeyDown/PreviewKeyDown events. The latter handles keys not included in TextInput events.

Comment: It worked! Now how can I read the backspace, the spacebar and the return keys in addition to the other keys?

Comment: @sikas - I believe you'd need to use KeyDown for things like Backspace/Delete, but general text input should be handled via TextInput. TextInput is smart about various things, like entering non-ASCII characters. Different languages have different rules/input. So typing "ab" in English will be "ab", but in another language it may result in an "a" with an accent/tilde on top.

Answer (score 2):

KeyPress event is what you are looking for I think. Warning: It does not work for non-character keys.

Comment: I can`t find KeyPress event in the list I see when I press "K" ... I can find KeyUp and KeyDown Only!!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(VS.90).aspx I do not know why you can't see it, but it is there

Comment: I guess it is not supported in WPF!

Comment: @sikas Correct. In WPF you'd probably want to use [KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.keydown.aspx).